# Can't resolve play sevice when compiling in Offline mode in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I sync all libraries, then I enable offline mode (via command line or on gradle tab) and then I always get this error:

```
 Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
```

I don't understand why this error occurs if I'm using version 17.0.0. Maybe some other libraries use play-services? But why they don't cache it too? I'm syncing from online before I'm trying to complie in offline.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have google() repository in project-level build.gradle before any others:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also Check this line in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I have this, everything works fine when I disable offline mode. But I want to fix offline mode.